# How to prevent beamer from removing the tab alignment of lstlisting?

Tags: beamer, listings

I want to show my C# code snippet on the presentation slides using `beamer`.
Because the code is long, I set the frame to be breakable using the frame option `allowframebreaks`. The code now can be shown in several frames. Unfortunately, the tab alignment in the original source no longer be preserved.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset%
{%
   language=[Sharp]C,
   backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
   basicstyle=\color{White}\tiny\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
   identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
   stringstyle=\color{Red}, 
   commentstyle=\color{Green},  
   breaklines=true,
   breakatwhitespace=true,
   tabsize=10,
   showstringspaces=false%
}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{MyListing}
\begin{lstlisting}
using System;

publid delegate void Foo(object o);

public class Program: object
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World");//This is a comment.
   /*This is a comment too.*/
 }
 public static void PSTricks(this object)
 {
   Say("I Love PSTricks!");

   Say("I Love PSTricks!");

   Say("I Love PSTricks!");

   Say("I Love PSTricks!");
 }

 public static void LaTeX(this object)
 {
   Say("I Love LaTeX too!");

   Say("I Love LaTeX too!");

   Say("I Love LaTeX too!");

   Say("I Love LaTeX too!");
 }

 public void Say(System.String message)
 {
   System.Text.StringBuilder sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();

   sb.Append(messange);

   Console.WriteLine(sb);
 }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit 1:

This bad behavior only happens for the inline inclusion.

The inclusion from an external file works well as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: @all, please see my update. This bad behavior only appears for inline inclusion. For external file inclusion, the problem vanishes. :-)

Comment: Herbert is right, you should try and make your examples _miminal_. To still reach the page break, use can use, e.g., `\setlength\paperheight{2cm}`. Moreover, please don't post overly long screen shots! A few lines are quite sufficient, and even better: Then it is easier to compare the screenshots.

Comment: @Hendrik. OK :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cannot work, because fragile material has to written into an external temporary file and then read back by beamer. The tabs get lost here. Use it this way:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\Lst{%
\begin{lstlisting}[tabsize=2,showtabs,frame=single]
using System;
                publid delegate void Foo(object o);
\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{MyListing}
\Lst
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and by the way: please provide *minimal* examples ... ;-)