# Code indentation gets lost in Beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim

For any unknown reason I have to use `verbatim` instead of `listings`.

Note: This issue also appear when using `listings` but [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8370/2099)  can fix it. Unfortunately, the trick Herbert used there cannot be applied here. I attempted to use the same trick but it failed as follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]
\Lst
{
    \begin{verbatim}
            class Foo
            {
                    public static void Main()
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine("hello xport");
                    }
            }
    \end{verbatim}
}

\begin{frame}{hello xport}
\Lst
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It was compiled by `pdflatex` and `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` provided by TeX Live 2010 on Windows 7. And my editor is TeXnicCenter.

---

### Caution:

If you want to try my code above, you must copy them in Edit mode. Copying the code directly from the rendered HTML will make my original tabs changed to spaces. :-)

Comment: I assume that `beamer` ignores all spaces outside `frame`s by default. Maybe place the code inside the frame and the `fragile` option.

Comment: I tested it and I got indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\defverbatim` ignores the tab character. Use instead spaces for the indentation or the package `fancyvrb` which can replace the tabs with a given number of spaces.